# Problem with dragging files on Pygame screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, screensharing

My project deals with sharing screen of one computer on another, similar to TeamViewer.
I use Python with Pygame to show the screen share, as my GUI.
One of my features is dragging a file/directory on the screen share to send this file or the directory to the other computer. It's easier to be done as Pygame has the abillity to detect a DROP event and to get the dropped item's path.
When I try to run this project on my computers, it works well. But when I'm trying to run it on the lab, as I'm trying to drop the file or directory on Pygame's screen, the cursor turns into a "block" sign and eventually what I dropped onto the screen is not detected, which also means that the DROP event is not triggered.
I assume that the operation system could be the reason for this. Maybe a setting on the computers that causes a rejection of the "drag and drop". I use windows 10 on both computers. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to uninstall the old version I had of Pygame (1.9.6) and then to reinstall it to the most recent version (2.0.1 as of today). Now the Drag and Drop eventually works perfectly. I've come to a conclusion that this problem occured because of the old version of Pygame that actually didn't allow me to use this feature. Now it's fixed.